# need help regarding a specific testng error for selenium script

Tags: java, selenium

I was executing the below,

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Applications/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    return driver;
}


@Test
public void firstTry() {
    getDriver().get("www.google.com");
}
```

Got the following as error.

```
Sep 03, 2018 3:39:20 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.is(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

Have imported all the required jars. Running it on macOS, is there a reason why i am getting this? Any answers will be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what is the exact problem you have

but you need to change like this if are using Windows. Need to add.exe in chromedriver and the add https:// in getting URL

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Applications/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    return driver;
}


@Test
public void firstTry() {
    getDriver().get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: the browser is not opening, nothing is happening, an the script gives an error. i am not on windows.

Comment: Ok i will check, you are using mac

Comment: Let me know selenium JARS you used and also are you usingDesiredCapabilities

Comment: not using desired capabilities. The jars i am using are selenium-java-3.14.0 , java-json.jar, selenium-java.jar, java-client-6.1.0.jar, selenium-chrome-driver-2.26.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use all latest jars and chromedriver.exe files

Use complete URL including with http

Looks like there is jars conflict, please also try with only one jar that is Selenium Standalone Server jar here https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ if issue is resolved then look into your jars. for java specific jars you can download from here https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf) on port 23838
Only local connections are allowed.
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
Sep 04, 2018 1:59:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Comment: getting the above comment as error when i changed the jars to the correct ones. a new chrome session is opening but not not navigating to the desired URL.

Comment: try complete url like http : // www . google.com  (without spaces)